# @angular/flex-layout causing annoying scrollbar in angular 11

Tags: angular, sass, angular-flex-layout

First time using @angular/flex-layout tried it on my new project. By showing `mat-card` in a for loop inside the flex-container. It adds up an annoying scrollbar I don't want to use fxFlex="column" on `xs` devices, I think `fxLayoutGap="20px grid"` is causing the issue. Here is stackblitz link: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-amv2z1?file=src/app/app.component.html)

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add fxFlexFill to the container

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="20px grid"
  fxFlexFill
   fxLayoutAlign="center center">
```